# conditional probability of independent events

Tags: probability

I have [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3zuv.png) colored cards and pick up one randomly.
There are 2 events:

- A = the number of the card is greater than 1
- B = the card is a triangle

The question is: solve p(not B | A)

I did:
p(A ∩ not B)/ p(A) = (3/6)/(5/6) = 3/5

Which, according to my book, is correct. However, since these are independent events (i think), the following should work also:
p(not B | A) = p(not B)
However, this gives me 3/6, which is not correct.

Why isn't p(not B) the correct answer? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you say they are independent events? Indeed they are not. If A is not satisfied then B is satisfied. This contradicts independence.

Comment: @mfl I thought they were independent but I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By noticing that you get a different answer, you have directly shown that the events are not independent.

To understand why they are not independent, note that if $A$ is true, then the probability of $B$ changes from $3/6$ to $3/5$. It may be even more obvious to note that if $A$ is false, then you know $B$ must be true.

Comment: Alright, I thought they were independent. Thanks!